# Flask Login - Using Firebase

Tags: flask-login

The below logs me in but keeps returning me to the login screen as there is an error somewhere. This confuses me though because it does log me in.

How can I debug this to get a more specific answer (find the actual error as to why its not passing.. if that is the issue) over the output in the console?

"GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 -

"GET /static/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -

```
@app.route("/result", methods = ["POST", "GET"])
def result():
if request.method == "POST":        #Only if data has been posted
    result = request.form           #Get the data
    email = result["email"]
    password = result["pass"]
    try:
        #Try signing in the user with the given information
        user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)
        #Insert the user data in the global person
        global person
        person["is_logged_in"] = True
        person["email"] = user["email"]
        person["uid"] = user["localId"]
        #Get the name of the user
        data = db.child("users").get()
        person["name"] = data.val()[person["uid"]]["name"]
        #Redirect to welcome page
        return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
    except:
        #If there is any error, redirect back to login
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
else:
    if person["is_logged_in"] == True:
        return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

I'm a data scientist by trade but new to flask.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a "view logs" page on heroku that you can view during deployment and while navigating your deployment.

Super helpful if you are outside of the command prompt.